# solar fails when search requirement is fuzzy and wildcard search

Tags: regex, apache, search, solr, autosuggest

what i need

- i need to build search like amazon and other e-com site using suggestive search .
- i have tried with wilcard search  it works like q=*string*; but i fails to search when wrong word says plnts , bcs only works 0,1 form.
- when i used fuzzy search q="string~1" it give result when plants->written plnts , but it fails in searching keyword zer for fertilizer.
- i have used suggestor but it is not fullfling search requirement link: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Suggester.
- im being struggling for 3 days to get solution .
- i have googled found link : https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/20b7db4ef2d4d55be661 typehaed js which twitter used.
- code i have used

  ```
      function startSolrSearch ()
      {
      var srchval = $("#productSearch").val().trim();
      if (srchval.length >= 1){
      srchval = srchval.replace(/'|"/g,"").replace(/ /g,"*+*");

      srchval = srchval.replace(/ /g,"+AND+");
          console.log(srchval);
      srchval = "*"+srchval+"*";


      for(var i = 0; i < solrPendingRequests.length; i++){
      solrPendingRequests[i].abort();
      }
      console.log(srchval);
      solrPendingRequests.push($.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : solrbasepath + "solr/afeef/select?q="+srchval+'~'+1+"&facet=true&facet.field=title&facet.field=keywords&facet.field=category&indent=on&qt=spellchecker&wt=json&hl=true&hl.fl=title+keywords+model_name&hl.simple.pre=<b>&hl.simple.post=<%2Fb>&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.snippets=1&start=0&rows=100",
      dataType : 'JSONP',
      cache : false,
      jsonp: 'json.wrf',
      success : function(html) {

      getSearchData (html);

      }
      }));
      } 
      else {


      $('#searchsuggestion .linkresults').html('');
      $('#searchsuggestion').hide();
      $('.close_search').hide();
      }
  ```

  url

  ```
    http://www.supplified.com:8983/solr/vikas/select?q=zer~1 OR q="*zer*" &ind   nt=on&q.op=AND&facet=true&facet.field=title&facet.field=keywords&debugQuery=on&qt=spellchecker&wt=json&hl=true&hl.fl=title+keywords+model_name&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.snippets=1&start=0&rows=10&json.wrf=jQuery111205813984868582338_1454571708911&_=1454571708913
  ```
- i need suggestion how i could used suggestive search like amazon used in  there e-com sites.

Answer (score 0):

Better you should use solr spellcheck component for having a better control over it. spellcheck provides a range of settings in it by which you can configure it according to your use case.

**And why the fuzzy query is not working while searching keyword zer for fertilizer?** Please refer this documentation for fuzzy searches.

[Fuzzy searches documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches)

*Lucene supports fuzzy searches based on the Levenshtein Distance, or Edit Distance algorithm. To do a fuzzy search use the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of a Single word Term. For example to search for a term similar in spelling to "roam" use the fuzzy search:
roam~
This search will find terms like foam and roams.
Starting with Lucene 1.9 an additional (optional) parameter can specify the required similarity. The value is between 0 and 1, with a value closer to 1 only terms with a higher similarity will be matched. For example:
roam~0.8
The default that is used if the parameter is not given is 0.5.*

You have mention similarity value = 1 for the match and hence it is not returning results. I think using small value in the similarity parameter can solve your problem (try values between 0 to 1 and see how it works).

Comment: thank mirad for answer but according url :    http://www.supplified.com:8983/solr/vikas/select?q={!q.op=AND%20df=title}zer~1&indent=on&q.op=AND&facet=true&facet.field=title&facet.field=keywords&debugQuery=on&qt=spellchecker&wt=json&hl=true&hl.fl=title+keywords+model_name&hl.simple.pre=%3Cb%3E&hl.simple.post=%3C%2Fb%3E&hl.usePhraseHighlighter=true&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.snippets=1&start=0&rows=10&json.wrf=jQuery111205813984868582338_1454571708911&_=1454571708913

Comment: i have also used spell checker though ist not working

Comment: hey Afeef, you have used zer~1, try using zer~0.5 or zer~0.4 in your query. Even if you use spellcheck component or write your own custom spellchecker algorithm you'll have to decide on the value of k in 'zer~ k' Keeping the value of k low you can have a wrong match also.